# Deleting User in new Yodlee API (DELETE)

Tags: yodlee

The documentation for the new Yodlee API is unclear with regard to deregistering/removing/deleting a user from the service.

The documentation does not specify any parameters for this endpoints beside the cobrand name. I assumed that a user token would be how the user is identified (provided in the authentication header), but when I try to delete a user I get this message:

```
{
  "errorCode": "Y400",
  "errorMessage": "Required String parameter 'loginName' is not present",
  "referenceCode": "Z1462344426689T4f24c"
}
```

So to address this,  I put the `loginName` as a string parameter, but I still get the same error.

What are the required string parameters? Are there any others in addition to the login name?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay in answering this. we will also ensure that document is tweaked for easy consumption.

The parameters to be passed for this call are **cobSession** and **userSession** in the Authorization header. Also, please note that this is a **DELETE** call and not POST.

Regards,
Vijay